# Performance parse Csv to bean java

Tags: java, read.csv

Can't reading csv file there are more than 5 million lines

Env: Java 8, opencsv -version 4.6, Lunix, MySQL

My code:

```py
public static <T> List<T> parseCsvToBeanPosition(Class<T> clazz, Reader readerInput) {
        ColumnPositionMappingStrategy ms = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy();
        ms.setType(clazz);
        CsvToBean<T> csvToBean =
                new CsvToBeanBuilder(readerInput)
                        .withType(clazz)
                        .withMappingStrategy(ms)
                        .build();
        return csvToBean.parse();
    }
```

```py
2019-06-21 16:38:13 [http-nio-8085-exec-2] INFO SynchronizeBusiness - Start parse:  (SynchronizeBusiness.java:223)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000abc80000, 284688384, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 284688384 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
```

Comment: Well, did you increase the JVM's max heap size? If so, does it exceed the OS' total memory (physical + virtual)?

Comment: You can fix those with `-Xmx1024m`, it is set to 1GB.

Comment: Do you have to keep everything in memory ? Because it s a better design to stream the reading. For Exemple using IterableCSVToBean instead of CsvToBean

Comment: What's your server's memory? What's your CSV file size?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your application consumes more memory than allocated (Default).

1. increase your memory allocation to JVM to -Xms2g -Xmx2g (If needed increase it more and try it out)